# Question with linear transformation and matrices, to try to reach conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. 
    $T(\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{bmatrix})$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-2x+y&-y + z\\3w&w\end{bmatrix} $. 
And there's a basis $B$ such that $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}a&1&0&0\\0&-2&0&0\\0&0&0&b\\0&0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}$. 
Then which of these statements is true? 
a) $a= 0$ and $b\ne 0$. 
b) $a = 1$ and $b=0$.
c) $a=-1$ and $b=1$. 
d) any $a$ and $b = 0$. 
e) $a=1$ and any $b$. 
My approach (The idea): I know that $ImT = Col[T]_B$, so I first found out that $dimImT=3$, so $Rank([T]_B)$ should be equal to $3$. so the answer isn't c,d,e. 
Now I got stuck in deciding if it's (a) or (b), since both of the answers lead to $Rank([T]_B) = 3$, and I couldn't figure out how to find the correct answer. 

I would really appreciate any hints or feedback, thanks in advance.